# EF cannot delete child object because of associationset

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have customers and bankaccounts. A customer can have multiple bankaccounts, but a bankaccount can have one customer.

I'm trying to remove a bankaccount by it's id. But when we remove things, we actually perform an update by setting the IsActive property to false.

My delete part looks like this:

```
var bankaccounts = from b in this.unitOfWork.BankAccounts
                    where command.Ids.Contains(b.Id) // command.ids is an array with id's
                    select b;

this.unitOfWork.BankAccounts.DeleteObject(bankaccounts);
```

Then, before the commit, we have this code that will convert the delete into an update and set the IsActive property to false

```
public void Commit()
{
    var addedEntities = this.GetEntitiesByState(EntityState.Added);
    foreach (var entity in addedEntities)
    {
        var property = this.GetIsActiveProperty(entity);
        property.SetValue(entity.Entity, true);
    }

    var deletedEntities = this.GetEntitiesByState(EntityState.Deleted);
    foreach (var entity in deletedEntities)
    {
        var property = this.GetIsActiveProperty(entity);
        if (property != null)
        {
            entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
            property.SetValue(entity.Entity, false);
        }
    }

    this.mapper.Commit();
}

private IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> GetEntitiesByState(EntityState state)
{
    return this.context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == state);
}

private PropertyInfo GetIsActiveProperty(DbEntityEntry entity)
{
    return entity.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
}
```

When I'm removing 'root' entities (like customer) this works well, but when I try to remove a 'child' entity, like bankaccount, I get this exception:

> A relationship from the 'CustomerBankAccounts ' AssociationSet is in
>   the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding
>   'BankAccount ' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

I'm not sure whyI get this error. I'm just updating my bankaccount, not removing it. Can someone explain why I get this exception and how I can fix this?

Comment: Off-topic: I posted this question. May be you can answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588993/ef-what-is-the-sql-output-when-using-contains-in-linq-query

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `DeleteObject` both the `BankAccount` and the relationship between that `BankAccount` and its `Customer` are marked for deletion.

Later you change the state of the `BankAccount` to `EntityState.Modified` instead of deleting it. However, the relationship to the `Customer` is still marked for deletion.

EntityFramework now wants to commit the changes and delete the relationship. Since this is an identifying relationship it expects that a `BankAccount` should be deleted along with it which is not the case. Thus the error message.

To fix this you need to set the relationship not to be deleted. <s>I don't have the code ready right now but I am assuming the same class that has the `GetEntitiesByState` method should also have a `GetRelationshipsByState` or something similar.</s>

The relationships also have an entry in the `DbChangeTracker.Entries()` list. You will need to figure out a way to find the right relationship that you want to keep but the place to do it is where your other detection code (`var property = this.GetIsActiveProperty(entity);` etc.) lives right now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But when I view the `DbChangeTracker.Entries()` list I only see the bankaccount from which I've changed the state. The list only has one entry.

Comment: I thought this was the list containing all the entities (including relationships). If it's not there, I don't know where it is right now. I do recall writing code that checks whether `entry.Entity` is null because that is the case for relationships.