# EF: What is the SQL output when using Contains in LINQ query?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, nhibernate

In NHibernate when we execute a query like the one below the SQL generated for it will contains parameters for each element in the collection. If the query is executed against MSSQL Server and there are 2k or more elements in the collection you will get an error because max parameters allowed by the sql engine is 2k.

```
var bankaccounts = from b in this.unitOfWork.BankAccounts
                    where command.Ids.Contains(b.Id) // command.ids is an array with id's
                    select b;
```

Sorry for being lazy to test this myself with EntityFramework but I see other developers writing such code: [EF cannot delete child object because of associationset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588674/ef-cannot-delete-child-object-because-of-associationset#17588674)

The question is what SQL will be generated from EF for this kind of queries?

Comment: You can see the generated SQL scripts using the SQL Profiler of SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've watched SQL profiler for you. This is what happens in Entity Framework (I quess this is wat NHibernate also will product, but I'm not sure..):

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[AccountNo] AS [AccountNo], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[IBAN] AS [IBAN], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[Customer_Id] AS [Customer_Id]
FROM [dbo].[BankAccounts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (4,5,6,7,9)
```

As you can see, it will become a `WHERE .. IN ([the contains values])`

Comment: Can you confirm that the numbers here 'IN (4,5,6,7,9)' are not passed as parameters? If they are not it sounds that EF handles this scenario very poorly :( 10x for checking this out for me.

Comment: No, they're not passed in as parameters. I've copied the SQL statement from SQL Provider into this answer.

Answer (score 2):

With this query,

```
    var ids = context.Countries
        .Take(10).Select(c => c.CountryId).ToList();

    var offices = context.Offices.Where(o => ids.Contains(o.CountryId))
        .ToList();
```

it will generate this SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[OfficeId] AS [OfficeId], 
[Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId],
[Extent1].[OfficeName] AS [OfficeName]
FROM [dbo].[Office] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CountryId] IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```